# Artemis cluster throws ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory

Tags: activemq-artemis

I prepared java application with embedded Artemis broker. It is single jar that contains all dependencies.
I use `org.apache.activemq:artemis-server:2.10.1` and I start broker in following way:

```
new EmbeddedActiveMQ().setConfigResourcePath( config ).start();
```

where `config` is a URL to configuration file.
I use one config file for master and one config file for slave.

master:

```
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
        <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://127.0.0.1:61617</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <bindings-directory>artemis/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>artemis/journal</journal-directory>
        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ"/>
                </anycast>
            </address>
        </addresses>

        <connectors>
            <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
            <connector name="artemis">tcp://127.0.0.1:61617</connector>
        </connectors>
        <cluster-user>artemis-cluster</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>artemis-cluster</cluster-password>


        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <address></address>
                <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        <ha-policy>
            <replication>
                <master/>
            </replication>
        </ha-policy>
    </core>

</configuration>
```

Slave:

```
<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://127.0.0.1:61618</acceptor>
    </acceptors>
    <bindings-directory>artemis/bindings</bindings-directory>
    <journal-directory>artemis/journal</journal-directory>
    <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <addresses>
        <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="DLQ"/>
            </anycast>
        </address>
    </addresses>

    <connectors>
        <!-- Connector used to be announced through cluster connections and notifications -->
        <connector name="artemis">tcp://127.0.0.1:61618</connector>
    </connectors>
    <cluster-user>artemis-cluster</cluster-user>
    <cluster-password>artemis-cluster</cluster-password>

    <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups>

    <discovery-groups>
        <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
            <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
        </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>

    <cluster-connections>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <address></address>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
        </cluster-connection>
    </cluster-connections>
    <ha-policy>
        <replication>
            <slave/>
        </replication>
    </ha-policy>


</core>
```

It works properly on Windows 10 and Centos 7. It does not work on Oracle Linux 7. All machines use the same Java version.

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.9+11, mixed mode)
```

There is no any exception on Windows and Centos and I see following logs:

```
11:14:30.867 [Thread-0] INFO  org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ221025: Replication: sending NIOSequentialFile...
```

and

```
11:14:33.911 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@2a3c96e3)] INFO  org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server - AMQ221031: backup announced
```

Exactly the same jar and exaclty the same configuration file throws exception on Oracle Linux:

```
11:31:56.074 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$6@63b1d4fa)] WARN  org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212025: did not connect the cluster connection to other nodes
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ClassloadingUtil.newInstanceFromClassLoader(ClassloadingUtil.java:59) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:996) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$2.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:993) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.instantiateConnectorFactory(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:993) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:181) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:798) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:655) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.connect(ServerLocatorImpl.java:637) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl$4.run(ServerLocatorImpl.java:595) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[broker.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [broker.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
        at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ClassloadingUtil.newInstanceFromClassLoader(ClassloadingUtil.java:55) ~[broker.jar:?]
        ... 15 more
```

Master and slave both throw the same exception. Why Artemis wants to use `org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory` on Oracle Linux? I debugged my application on Windows and `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory` is used there. Where it can be configured? Maybe there is some configuration file in user directory or sth like that? Probably I can solve the issue by adding hornetq to dependencies but I prefer to use NettyConnectorFactory  from Artemis. I do not understand why one machine uses different NettyConnectorFactory than the other two machines.

Comment: I cannot debug application on Oracle Linux so I debug it only on Windows. As I understand the way it works it seems that transport configuration is received from broadcast. It seems that there is some other broker (or sth) that broadcasts its group and it broadcasts 'org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory' in transport configuration. I changed IP and port in broadcast-group  and discovery-group but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I got access to Oracle Linux and I can debug it now. As I wrote in my previous comment there is some endpoint that broadcasts transport configuration for `org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory`. It broadcasts its ip and port. I do not know why changing `group-address`and `group-port` does not solve this issue.

Comment: Have you changed `group-address` and `group-port` for broadcast-groups and discovery-groups?

Comment: I used original configuration file by mistake so actually I did not changed group-address and group-port (I only thought that I changed) . Changing group-addressand and group-port  solves this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly being caused by a HornetQ broker on your network which is using the same `group-address` and `group-port` (i.e. `231.7.7.7:9876`) to broadcast its connector information. You're using the default values so this isn't terribly surprising. You should either find this HornetQ broker and stop it or change your Artemis' cluster configuration to use a different `group-address` and/or `group-port`.